# Pythonic way to group list of objects by list of str

Tags: python, sorting, python-dataclasses

I have a data class e.g

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Place:
    name: str
    tags: List[str]
```

And a list of objects:

```
places = [Place(name='Foo', tags=['tagA', 'tagB']), Place(name='Bar', tags=['tagB', 'tagC']), ...]
```

If I wanted to group 10000x objects by tag e.g

```
{
    'tagA': [Place(name='Foo', tags=['tagA', 'tagB'])],
    'tagB': [Place(name='Foo', tags=['tagA', 'tagB']), Place(name='Bar', tags=['tagB', 'tagC'])],
    'tagC': [Place(name='Bar', tags=['tagB', 'tagC'])]
}
```

One approach would be loop through the list and then the list of tags and build up a dictionary.

But is there better way of doing this? Perhaps using `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Sure, you can use `itertools.groupby`. But it won't be more efficient. `itertools` isn't some magic wand; it's a bunch of for loops wrapped in neat functions. Very useful for writing self-documenting code, but no more efficient than writing the loops yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` is only useful/efficient if:

1. You can apply an ordering to your input such that all intended members of a group are adjacent, and
2. No item should belong to multiple groups.

Your described use case violates both criteria (each item belongs to as many groups as it has tags, there is no reasonable sort order that would group them), so `itertools.groupby` is inappropriate. The correct solution is the one you describe; make a `dict` (or for convenience, a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to avoid needing to muck about with membership testing and/or `setdefault` calls), iterate all your objects, add them to all appropriate keys, e.g.:

```
from collections import defaultdict

places = ...

places_by_tag = defaultdict(list)
for place in places:
    for tag in place.tags:
        places_by_tag[tag].append(place)
```

which is about as efficient as can be; each place/tag pair is iterated exactly once, and the `dict` lookup, while technically worst-case `O(n)`, is average case `O(1)`. The only meaningful optimization available would be if the tags could be easily converted to indices into a `list` of fixed size, reducing average case `O(1)` to *actual* `O(1)`, but that's highly unlikely to matter (trying to improve on it is premature optimization).